# What's wrong with: is_number if true do 1 end

Tags: elixir

Why is the second form parsed as 2 args being passed to is_number?

```
is_number if true, do: 1
true

is_number if true do 1 end
** (CompileError) iex:42: undefined function is_number/2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the [quoting mechanism](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/quote-and-unquote.html) to see how an expression is being parsed in Elixir.

```
iex(6)> IO.puts Macro.to_string(quote do: (is_number if true, do: 1))
is_number(if(true) do
  1
end)
:ok
iex(7)> IO.puts Macro.to_string(quote do: (is_number if true do 1 end))
is_number(if(true)) do
  1
end
:ok
```

So in your first case, the `do` gets parsed as an argument to `if`, and the whole thing gets passed to `is_number`. In the second, the `do` has a different precedence and ends up binding to the `is_number` call itself as a second argument, so we end up calling `if/1` and `is_number/2`, which is nonsense.

As for why this is, it's common to use `do` to capture full expressions as statements, like

```
if something_really_complicated arg1, arg2, arg3 do
  # ...
end
```

So, in this case, it makes sense to bind `do` as loosely as possible. Conversely, if we try to pass `do:` as a keyword argument with an explicit comma, then it's just an argument like any other, so it follows the usual argument passing rules rather than a special one.

The key thing to remember in a language like Elixir is that many things that are keywords in other languages really aren't in Elixir. `if` statements parse exactly the same way macros would, and you can write your own `if` macro easily, and `do:` is really just a keyword argument that has a bit of syntax sugar attached to it, not anything specific to any particular control statement. This is a big part of what makes Elixir (and company) excellent for domain-specific tasks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ruby, do they really have if statements with arguments as in your example?  I skimmed a few tutorials and didn't see that.

So to get this straight in my head - Elixir will essentially pass any do ... end clause to it's outermost function.  Is that it in a nutshell?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. In Ruby, `if` is actually a special keyword. I was talking about Elixir with respect to the `do` semantics. I've edited out the reference to Ruby, as it wasn't really necessary to the substance of my answer. But in Elixir, you are correct. `do .. end` simply gets made into a keyword argument whose name is `do:` and passed to the outermost function. In fact, I just tested it, and `if` is a macro in Elixir as well; it compiles to `case` (which is a keyword).

Comment: I struggle to understand why `do` is bound to `is_number(if(true))`. Are parenthesis useless at this point? We call `is_number` with parenthesis which should explicitly tell the compiler what the arguments are. The arguments are `if(true)` which is nonsense. It's very unintuitive why `do` gets "put" into the same argument list when it's not within the parenthesis.